# tensorflow: use py_func to define custom learning rate decay before applied to optimizer

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement a custom learning rate decay. The detail is: 0.01 as initial_learning_rate, and after 50 iterations, the lr (learning rate) decays to 0.001 and after 70, down to 0.0001. So in my code *self.lr_decay_iters* is a list [50, 70]. And I implemented it by tf.py_func ( *def _custom_lr()* ). Then add to the optimizer. Here is my relative snippet:

```
def _custom_lr(self, lr):
    if (len(self.lr_decay_iters) > 0 and
            self.sess.run(self.global_step) >= self.lr_decay_iters[0]):
        lr *= self.decay_factor
        self.lr_decay_iters.pop(0)
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

    return (lr).astype(np.float32)

def get_opt(self):
    name = self.OPT['name']
    args = self.OPT['args'] if 'args' in self.OPT else {}

    # custom learning rate strategy
    lr = tf.Variable(self.initial_learning_rate, trainable=False,
                     name='learning_rate', dtype=tf.float32)
    lr = tf.py_func(self._custom_lr, [lr], tf.float32)
    tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate', lr)
    self.learning_rate = lr

    if not hasattr(tf.train, '%sOptimizer' % name):
        raise ValueError('%s optimizer not support', name)

    optimizer = getattr(tf.train, '%sOptimizer' % name)
    return optimizer(lr, **args)
```

But the result is:

1. When stop at the *ipdb* line (breakpoint), I get the right results.
2. But from tensorboard, the lr is always 0.01 up to 200 iterations.

Whether my lr applied to optimizer decays or not?

Otherwise, *self.global_step* is a tf.Variable.

Comment: My guess would be that `optimizer()` saves the learning rate, making it constant and to change it, you would need to implement another Optimizer yourself.

Comment: But how the api `tf.train.exponential_decay` implements, which can genertate the op before `learning rate` applied to the optimizer.

Comment: Are you trying to modify `lr` TensorFlow variable from inside py_func? You can't do that, inside your `py_func` - `lr` is a numpy value of `lr` TensorFlow variable, so `*=` doesn't affect value of that var

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov I know the `lr` (inside the py_func) is the numpy value of the var beforehand. But maybe I misunderstand the use of py_func. Is that can only modify the *vars* started from `tf.placeholder`? Otherwise, `py_func` is so promising in my perspective, while there are few notes about it.

Comment: `py_func` is essentially a shorthand for doing `session.run` to fetch values as numpy arrays, manipulating them and feeding them back through `feed_dict`. If you want to modify TensorFlow variable you need to do `sess.run` on a `var.assign` op

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I previously thought it as an alternative to adding a custom op (C++). And I did try `var.assign`, but forgot to add the op to `session.run`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Python op is special because it just executes content in main Python interpreter. Python interpreter can't use more than one core and can't run on GPU, some more caveats in this commit [e3209bd3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e3209bd3)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you very much. I'll dig deeper into the source code, cause I feel I'm lack of knowledges of rationales of some ops.